# TextToSpeech initialization on Android -- what if it fails?

Tags: java, android, constructor, text-to-speech, initializer

In Android, if a TextToSpeech instance fails to initialize (the callback invoked indicating the completion of the TextToSpeech engine initialization returns TextToSpeech.ERROR), does that mean that subsequent attempted method calls to that instance will result in null pointer exceptions?

Example...

We initialize the object:

```
t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    Log.i("XXX", "There was an error initializing the TTS");
                }
            }
        });
```

... let's say the init fails, but we then go on to do something like:

```
t1.speak("hello");
```

Will this crash... or just say nothing?  The reason I ask is that if it does crash, then obviously I would have to put null checks everywhere.

Also, the reason I can't just find out for myself is that I don't know how to simulate the error.

Thanks for any prior knowledge.

Comment: You should show error logcat

Comment: I'm not experiencing an error.  I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: @MeosCoder There is no crash. You don't understand the question, he is asking what happens IF the error occurs, but he can't trigger the error behavior himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your main question read the docs of the `speak()` method ([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#speak)):

> This method is asynchronous, i.e. the method just adds the request to
>   the queue of TTS requests and then returns.

So unless your `tts` instance is `null`, it shouldn't throw any exception or crash the app, but just return the error code.

> Also, the reason I can't just find out for myself is that I don't know how to simulate the error.

Try to use constructor ([see docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#TextToSpeech(android.content.Context,%20android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,%20java.lang.String))) that expects as third parameter `String engine` and put invalid package name there. It should probably result in error then. (or disable/uninstall all TTS engines on your device/emulator)

Important thing to note regarding constructor is:

> In a case of a failure the listener may be called immediately, before TextToSpeech instance is fully constructed.

So unless the status is `SUCCESS`, you shouldn't touch your `tts` **in the listener** (of course you can use the `tts` afterwards as in your example) because it might not even be assigned / initialized yet.

Comment: "Unless your TTS instance is null, it shouldn't throw any exception". Well, that's until you get a NullPointerException `TextToSpeech.onInit()` while trying to use the instance... you try to fix the exception by `if tts == null { tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this) }` inside the `onInit` call... now there's no NullPointerException, but StackOverflowException instead while using `new` statement. The StackTrace only touches that line of code of mine (the rest are Android libraries)... and while commenting this, I think I figured it out: maybe `new TextToSpeech` while `onInit` is an infinite loop

Comment: @SebasSBM Well if you haven't got `status==SUCCESS` in the onInit() call, then the callback was probably called immediately inside the constructor call, so the resulting instance wasn't assigned to your tts variable yet and it's null. But calling the constructor again with the same listener object inside the onInit() method will make it into infinite recursive call and you end up with the StackOverflowException. Feel free to create new question with your problem and code so I can provide better answer for you.

Comment: I already made a patch with your information. Anyway I cannot test it (error doesn't happen in my machine). Anyway, I am curious what will happen. Instead of using `new`, I now just do what `onInit()` was doing before but if and only `if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)`... but I wonder: what if not? Will it retry `onInit()` under the hood? Anyways, at least it will fix the crash I had

Comment: @SebasSBM The initialization fails only when it can't access the required TTS. E.g. if you specify 3rd parameter (package name of your desired TTS engine) but it isn't installed on the device or it cannot be accessed by security means (e.g. you haven't set <queries> in AndroidManifest.xml correctly for Android 11+). If this happens, you can try to create new instance **without the 3rd** parameter to use default TTS. But if even that fails, you just need to give up, because result will be the same. I think this will happen only when user uninstalled the system TTS, or something like that.

Comment: once I upload the next version and Google's pre-launch report does its thing, I will know... there were some NullPointerExceptions of TTS instance `onInit()`... maybe just the error check conditional will fix it, we'll see...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code.

Use `language_codes` from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp.

```
mLanguage = new Locale(language_codes);

tts = new TextToSpeech(mContext, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                int result = tts.setLanguage(mLanguage);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("Text2SpeechWidget", result + " is not supported");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I implemented this solution to fix my code from NullPointerException over `tts` object. Not via anonymous `onInit` listener, but I did. However I wonder if `onInit` would be somehow retried if  `status == TextToSpeech.ERROR` under the hood or something... anyways, I use this as a patch for now

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, then I noticed that on some devices TTS may be deactivated. So I've just done the following

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.google.android.tts&hl=fr");
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.google.android.tts&hl=fr")));
        }
    }
```